# OpenGL - What is the order of operation for rotating a cube then placing it at an offset from another cube

Tags: opengl

I'm using OpenGL, loading mesh data for multiple meshes, and this is what i'm trying to do.

I would like to rotate and object, then place it at an offset from another object ( this would simulate an arm moving around the 'body' mesh ). How can I accomplish this.

currently, my 'limb' mesh is flying around the main object due to some miscalculation. Can any one help. Maybe give some examples of how glTranslate and glRotation work, and in what order.

this is in ModelView mode

As I understand it, a translation of 1, 0, 0 and then -1, 0, 0, should put me at 0, 0, 0.
Also, a rotation of 1, 0, 0, and then -1, 0, 0, should put me back at 0, 0, 0 as well

here is code from the Translate Rotation section

```
            // Remove Limb Offset
            gl.glTranslatef(
                    -object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.x,
                    -object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.y,
                    -object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.z
                );

            // Rotate Limb
            gmv = object.get(id).Limb.get(i).angle;
            gl.glRotatef( -gmv.x, 1, 0, 0 );
            gl.glRotatef( -gmv.y, 0, 1, 0 );
            gl.glRotatef( -gmv.z, 0, 0, 1 );

            // Restore Limb Offset
            gl.glTranslatef(
                    object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.x,
                    object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.y,
                    object.get(id).Limb.get(i).offset.z
                );

            // Camera Rotation
            gl.glRotatef( gm.gm3D.gmCamera.ang.x, 1, 0, 0 );
            gl.glRotatef( gm.gm3D.gmCamera.ang.y, 0, 1, 0 );
            gl.glRotatef( gm.gm3D.gmCamera.ang.z, 0, 0, 1 );

            // Main 'Body' mesh rotation
            gl.glTranslatef(
                    object.get( id ).Limb.get( 0 ).position.x - gm.gm3D.gmCamera.pos.x,
                    object.get( id ).Limb.get( 0 ).position.y - gm.gm3D.gmCamera.pos.y,
                    object.get( id ).Limb.get( 0 ).position.z - gm.gm3D.gmCamera.pos.z
                );

            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,
                    object.get(id).Limb.get(i).Buffer.panelSize,
                    GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                    object.get(id).Limb.get(i).Buffer.panelBuffer );
```

My mesh draws but the limb rotates away from the body at a high speed, and never stays near the 'body' mesh.

I honestly feel that my understanding of the order of operation of Translations and Rotations is missing something. Can someone help please?

---

Thanks for your response. You are right. I forgot to add Push and Pop Matrix calls in between each set of translation and rotation sets. Also, i think its worth mentioning here, after I added my pushes and pops, i forgot that the stack is processed First-In-Last-Out order ( for anyone having the same problem ). - Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rotate an object and then translate it, the translation will have been rotated as well, so the direction the rendered mesh moves wont be what you want unless you apply the inverse rotation to the to the translation vector.

Also, doing your rotations sequentially as you are isn't likely to produce the results you expect.  You should be converting the Euler angles you're using into a 4x4 matrix and apply it as a single rotation operation using `glMultMatrix`.  Plus, storing your object transforms individually as rotation (in Euler angles) and translation is going to make your work much harder than it needs to be.  Each object can store both translation and rotation  as a single 4x4 transform matrix.

If you're going to traverse a scene graph, where objects inherit from their parent's transformation, you should use (or implement) a matrix stack.  The use of `glRotatef` and `glTranslatef` makes it clear you're using the old GL 1.x matrix functionality, so you should look at `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`.

Since the limb should be relative to the body / torso, start out by applying the torso transform, doing the translation and then the rotation.  Once you've done this, use `glPushMatrix` to push the modelview matrix.  All further operations will be done using the new transform as the basis, until you call `glPopMatrix`.

A pseudo-code version of this would look something like this:

```
applyTransformation(body.transform);
renderMesh(body);
pushMatrix();
  applyTransformation(limb.transform);
  renderMesh(limb);
popMatrix();
```